# Page Number styling in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How to put the page numbers inside a logo in book in LaTeX. That is, in the book, at the footer, I want to add a logo and inside the logo the page number. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
%\includegraphics[scale=.25]{logo.png} this line throws an error ---> just to include a simple image for demo
\chapter{A Sample Chapter}
This is a sample chapter.
\end{document}
```

This is my logo:

[image]

Comment: The error has gone but it doesn't seem to work... @cmhughes

Comment: Defining headers and footers is document-wide, and so should be done in the document preamble, ie, before the `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us hit the small bird with a huge cannon ;)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,blindtext,tikz}
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%   
   \fancyhf{}%
   \fancyfoot[C]{\tikz[baseline={(0,0)},anchor=center] \node[label={center:\thepage}]{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{pecemblem}};}%
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}%
%% without the following the chapter pages won't have fancy page style
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
\makeatother
%
\pagestyle{myfancy}
\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\fancyfoot[C]{...` if you use `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{....`, you get this:

[image]

## Edit:

With your logo, may be this is what you want:

```
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\tikz[baseline={(0,0)},anchor=center] \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,label={[xshift=-.13cm,yshift=0.1cm]center:\footnotesize\thepage}]
    {\includegraphics[scale=.15]{logoSSS}};}%
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: @subhamsoni: Please don't post multiple comments when _one_ is enough. You can _edit_ your comments.